# Количество трисов в статистике Unity не соответствует реальному

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-android

Вот кадр с запущенной игрой. Камера просто смотрит на стену с картиной. Объектов минимум. И тем не менее статистика показывает 1.1 миллиона треугольников.

[image: Скриншот 1]

Вот кадр из редактора, который демонстрирует, что здесь никак не может быть такое количество полигонов.

[image: Скриншот2]

Я не понимаю, что происходит и как с этим бороться.

Comment: А скрин сцены можно и FrameDebug? А это вы в PlayMode смотрите?

Comment: У меня второй скрин как раз из окна сцены с включённой полигональной сеткой. Во FrameDebug оооочень много всего скринить. Опытным путём у меня получается такая ситуация, что камера как бы "видит" полигоны за существующими объектами и они, соответственно, учитываются в статистике.То есть, за этой стенкой с портретами и у меня две другие комнаты. Соответственно если я убираю их, то у меня снижается и количество трисов в статистике. Но ведь так же быть не должно? Occlusion Culling включён.

Comment: "Occlusion Culling включён". А вы этот Occlusion Culling запекали для своих комнат? Одной галочки не достаточно. Там надо указать объект что из них Occludee, а что Occluder. Зайти в окно Occlusion Culling и запечь(Bake).